# using stored procedure in crystal reports asp.net

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports-2008

I want to fatch data from sql server stored procedure in creating a crystal report.
How to do that.

Please Help

Answer (score 2):

Just create the Stored Procedure in your database and the set the DataSource in the Crystal Report to the Stored Procedure you have just created.

[Using Stored Procedures to create Crystal Reports](http://www.pdssoftware.com/newsletter/mar07/page6.htm)